# Flutter not playing audio in release mode

Tags: android, flutter

I have a flutter app that plays an audio alert when it receives a push notification. however I have noticed that recently (after making several changes to upgrade to flutter 3.7.8) this audio no longer plays when the app is in release mode while it functions as expected in debug mode. When running the app in release mode I have seen this message in the debug console `Dart Error: Dart_LookupLibrary: library 'package:my_app/infrastructure/notifications/push_notification_service.dart' not found.` so it does appear that this package (this is an internal .dart file in my lib directory and not an external package) this may be a red herring but as it mentions the push notification service I don't believe it is.

I'm kind of at a loss as to why this would be suddenly become an issue and only in release mode.

So far I have tried

- inspecting the APK just incase the audio asset was missing
- removing my newly added proguard rules
- adding a new rule `-keep class com.yourapp.package.name.infrastructure.notifications.** { *; }`
- building the app with `--no-shrink --no-obfuscate`

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated

Issue opened on flutter repo https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/123958

Comment: If your function is a top level function then can you try declaring `@pragma('vm:entry-point')` at the top of your function. Like this (sorry for inline code) `@pragma('vm:entry-point') \n topLevelFunction() {}`.

Comment: @JustaPerson I don't believe it as a top level function, just a class that have methods to create some notification channels

Comment: Then I would suggest you to open a new issue in flutter github repo.

Comment: Have opened an issue so will see what they say @JustaPerson thanks for your input

Comment: Turns out your fix, was correct @JustaPerson my apologies